# Logitech LS21 recognized as 2.0 system - Windows 8.1 doesn't detect Subwoofer

Tags: windows-8.1, logitech-speakers

I got my dad a Logitech LS21 system for Christmas. It's a 2.1 system, but it's recognized in Windows 8 as a 2.0 system (it says there is no subwoofer connected).

How would I go about getting the sub recognized?  It plays some sound now, but it's so quiet you can't hear it without putting your ear right next to it.

Answer (score 2):

The sub has a dial for controlling the *thump*, at the back - Lots of 2.1 systems connect like a 2.0 system, with a stereo cord going to the subwoofer, with a crossover sending out sound to the speakers. In general subwoofers are more 'felt' than heard, but yours is probably turned down.

If you have a 5.1 or better system the subwoofer has its own connector but here, the magic is entirely done on the speaker's inbuilt amplifier. While your system will 'see' this as a two speaker system, its not. Everything is working as designed.

All you need to do is to turn up this knob to taste

[image: enter link description here]

(image captured from [tigerdirect's youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=SG&hl=en-GB&v=CybNatbEDuE))

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  When it's turned down, it's completely inaudible.  When it's turned up, it can barely be heard.  Are you saying it's designed to be quiet?  Is there some way to position it so that it's more pronounced?

Comment: you don't usually hear it. The frequencies are meant to be felt, more than heard, assuming nothing's broken.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the two satellite speakers are connected so the "SPEAKER OUTPUT" jack on the back of the subwoofer. Then, find the green 3.5 mm plug and plug *THAT* into the computer. It should work that way, as I have a really similar system, the Logitech Z213. The one I have is essentially the successor to the Ls21.