# Logitech LS21 recognized as 2.0 system?

Tags: windows-8, audio, hardware-failure

Got my girlfriend a Logitech LS21 system for Christmas. It's a 2.1 system, but it's recognized in Windows 8 as a 2.0 system (it says there is no subwoofer connected). How would I go about getting the sub recognized? It plays some sound now, but it's so quiet you can't hear it without putting your ear right next to it.

It could be a problem with the sound card I've read somewhere. When the sub is turned down low with the knob on the back no sound, when turned up full you can hardly feel or hear the vibrations, so I decided to test on my mac they work fine, sub is nice and loud as it should be.

Does anyone have an answer on how to get the subwoofer recognized? I heard `asio4all` might work by playing with the sample rate? Or downloading new drivers but there are none on the logic tech site at the moment so maybe something realtek?

Comment: I thought you got the system for [your dad](http://superuser.com/questions/693585/logitech-ls21-recognized-as-2-0-system)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going by memory here, so I may be wrong. (z313 as a reference, which is similar enough)

Simply put, with this system the subwoofer is not a separate device from the perspective of the computer. You plug the sub into the main line out/speaker port, and plug the front left and right into the subwoofer. Internally, they pass the lower frequencies to the sub and the higher to the front left/right. All the computer really knows is to send all output (all frequencies) to the line out.

Most modern desktop computers have a separate sub out. Since the sub in this system is not a dedicated device, you should not be using that port.

---

The drivers for your audio chip (usually onboard, depends on motherboard but usually Realtek - download from motherboard manufacturer website) are what you want to use if you want some finer control.

Comment: I have it set up the way the instructions and you have just said. It is a relatively new laptop only 2-3 months old. how would I go about fixing the problem once I've downloaded these, or should it fix itself?

Comment: @matey A laptop is a slightly different matter - you're best off looking at the manufacturer's website for any drivers, though they do come preinstalled. Could you tell use the laptop model? Unfortunately, some laptops don't offer much in the way of audio adjustment. Also, your question seems to be a dupe of [this one](http://superuser.com/a/693588/117590), which may be helpful.

Comment: Yeh thats what I thought bob, checked both logitech and toshiba for new drivers but theres nothing that I think will fix this problem. Think i'm going to just fire them back to the shop hope try something else ha. Thanks for your help.